# Submit actions disappeared from Sitecore 9 forms editor

Tags: sitecore-forms

My team is experiencing an issue with Submit Actions in the Sitecore 9.0.1 Form Editor. When trying to edit existing submit actions, the edit button is disabled. And when trying to add a new one the "+" dropdown says there are no actions to display. I've tried reindexing the Form tree, rebuilding the core and master indexes, running unicorn, and republishing the site. This issue is present in all of our Sitecore environments from dev up to production. I see all the items related to our submit actions in the core db. Logging into Sitecore through an incognito window seems to fix the problem temporarily, however once I published the form I updated, the same issue appeared again.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: No actions to display]

[image: Disabled edit action button]

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. We don't want to have to jump through hoops every time we need to add or update submit actions. Thanks!

Comment: I've seen similar issues when using Azure search. Can you replicate on a vanilla instance running solr?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache, it worked for me when I experienced the same error

Comment: Any updates on this, @sche49? According to this similar question it could have very well been a browser caching issue: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/sitecore-9-2-forms-there-are-no-actions-to-display?rq=1

Comment: Any Updated on this issue ?

Comment: Clearing the browser cache or using the incognito window temporarily fixed the problem, but I don't believe that it was actually the cause of the issue. However, I am no longer with that company to confirm whether or not the issue was resolved or how it was resolved. Sorry folks.

Comment: Could you try to check the permissions for the Forms Submit action template, It could be because of some permission changes on Submit button action field?