# Sitecore 9.2 Forms - "There are no actions to display"

Tags: sitecore-forms

I'm using Sitecore Forms. With a Fresh install of Sitecore 9.2 and I don't see any submit actions. As far as I have read, it should come with 5 different standard presets.

Any idea what I'm missing or what's wrong?

[image: There are no actions to display]

**EDIT**
After looking again it looks like i get this Error message in my console.

```
{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"The required anti-forgery form field \"__RequestVerificationToken\" is not present.","exceptionType":"System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException","stackTrace":"   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext)\r\n   at Sitecore.Web.Http.Filters.ValidateHttpAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)"}
```

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache

Comment: @MarekMusielak Thank you. I had to do a total cache clear, and not just on the page. And then it worked.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I added some more information and converted my comment into an answer.

Comment: Try logging out and in again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This data is stored in a browser's cache and if it's there, browser doesn't send requests again to the server to get updated information.

It may happen that before some internal caches are rebuilt, you sent the first request and you receive "There are no actions to display" message.

If that's the case, clearing the browser's cache and maybe restarting the browser after.

Comment: Thanks for this fix. It's kind of annoying that you have to do this, feels like a bug to me. Another option that worked for me was to use an different browser (ideally one you've never opened the form in before) and then the list showed up fine.

Comment: yeah, that's annoying